# Change an element's background color when clicking a different element

Tags: javascript

I am expecting the element, `id="colorDisp"` to change color when I run one of the functions below, but instead the `body` element changes color.

Code below:

```js
function red()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 }
function blue()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
 }
function yellow()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
 }
function green()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
 } 
function orange()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
 }
function violet()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "violet";
 }
function grey()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
 }
function black()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
 }
function cream()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffe6e6";
 }
function fushia()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ff00bf";
 }
function white()
 {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
 }
```

```html
<center>
 <table style="padding-top: 200px;font-size:45">
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color:#ff0040"><a href = "#" onclick = "red()">red</a></td>
   <td style="background-color:#00bfff"><a href = "#" onclick = "blue()">blue</a></td>
   <td rowspan="5"width="300px" id="colorDisp" style="background-color:black"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color:#ffff00"><a href = "#" onclick = "yellow()">yellow</a></td>
   <td style="background-color:#80ff00"><a href = "#" onclick = "green()">green</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color:#ffbf00"><a href = "#" onclick = "orange()">orange</a></td>
   <td style="background-color:#8000ff"><a href = "#" onclick = "violet()">violet</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color:#808080"><a href = "#" onclick = "grey()">grey</a></td>
   <td style="background-color:#000000"><a href = "#" onclick = "black()">black</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color:#ffe6e6"><a href = "#" onclick = "cream()">cream</a></td>
   <td style="background-color:#ff00bf"><a href = "#" onclick = "fushia()">fushia</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
</center>
```

[Example output for the code above:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lze2a.jpg)

```
[1]http://i.imgur.com/lhqdFoi.jpg
```

[This is sample output for my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyOTz.jpg)

```
[2]http://i.imgur.com/cZw4iT3.jpg
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: its posted in the 2nd image but anyways the original code when u click red the background color will become red but I want to have to have the back ground color in td id:colorDisp or in specific data in table

Comment: thanks you very much guys for the help. I'm learning

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the td element with id `colorDisp` and not the `document.body`. You can also pass the color to one single JavaScript function which applies it to the element.

```js
function colorize(color)
{
       document.getElementById("colorDisp").style.background = color;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <center>
        <table style="/*padding-top: 200px;*/font-size:45">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ff0040"><a href = "#" onclick = "colorize('red')">red</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#00bfff"><a href = "#" onclick = "colorize('blue')">blue</a></td>
                <td rowspan="5" width="300px" id="colorDisp" style="background-color:black"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffff00"><a href = "#" onclick = "colorize('yellow')">yellow</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#80ff00"><a href = "#" onclick = "colorize('green')">green</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffbf00"><a href = "#" onclick = "colorize('orange')">orange</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#8000ff"><a href = "#" onclick = "colorize('violet')">violet</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#808080"><a href = "#" onclick = "colorize('grey')">grey</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#000000"><a href = "#" onclick = "colorize('black')">black</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffe6e6"><a href = "#" onclick = "colorize('#ffe6e6')">cream</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#ff00bf"><a href = "#" onclick = "colorize('#ff00bf')">fushia</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `body` by the the tag you want to display the color and in your code, it's `getElementById('colorDisp')`. Here is solution:

```js
function red()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
function blue()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
function yellow()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
function green()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }   
function orange()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    }
function violet()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "violet";
    }
function grey()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    }
function black()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
function cream()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "#ffe6e6";
    }
function fushia()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "#ff00bf";
    }
function white()
    {
        document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <center>
        <table style="padding-top: 200px;font-size:45">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ff0040"><a href = "#" onclick = "red()">red</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#00bfff"><a href = "#" onclick = "blue()">blue</a></td>
                <td rowspan="5"width="300px" id="colorDisp" style="background-color:black"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffff00"><a href = "#" onclick = "yellow()">yellow</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#80ff00"><a href = "#" onclick = "green()">green</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffbf00"><a href = "#" onclick = "orange()">orange</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#8000ff"><a href = "#" onclick = "violet()">violet</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#808080"><a href = "#" onclick = "grey()">grey</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#000000"><a href = "#" onclick = "black()">black</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffe6e6"><a href = "#" onclick = "cream()">cream</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#ff00bf"><a href = "#" onclick = "fushia()">fushia</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </center>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need multiple function for this. Try the following:

```js
function changeColor(color)
{
    document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<center>
        <table style="padding-top: 10px;font-size:45">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ff0040"><a href = "#" onclick = "changeColor('red')">red</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#00bfff"><a href = "#" onclick = "changeColor('blue')">blue</a></td>
                <td rowspan="5"width="300px" id="colorDisp" style="background-color:black"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffff00"><a href = "#" onclick = "changeColor('yellow')">yellow</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#80ff00"><a href = "#" onclick = "changeColor('green')">green</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffbf00"><a href = "#" onclick = "changeColor('orange')">orange</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#8000ff"><a href = "#" onclick = "changeColor('violet')">violet</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#808080"><a href = "#" onclick = "changeColor('grey')">grey</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#000000"><a href = "#" onclick = "changeColor('black')">black</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffe6e6"><a href = "#" onclick = "changeColor('#ffe6e6')">cream</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#ff00bf"><a href = "#" onclick = "changeColor('#ffe6e6')">fushia</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this. The code is much nicer (Here is the example http://plnkr.co/edit/FSwM1fDyzB7YgT4Or4B2?p=preview)

```
function updateColor(event)
{
    var color = event.parentElement.style.backgroundColor;
    document.getElementById('colorDisp').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Html:

```
<table style="padding-top: 200px;font-size:45">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ff0040"><a href = "#" onclick = "updateColor(this)">red</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#00bfff"><a href = "#" onclick = "updateColor(this)">blue</a></td>
                <td rowspan="5"width="300px" id="colorDisp" style="background-color:black"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffff00"><a href = "#" onclick = "updateColor(this)">yellow</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#80ff00"><a href = "#" onclick = "updateColor(this)">green</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffbf00"><a href = "#" onclick = "updateColor(this)">orange</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#8000ff"><a href = "#" onclick = "updateColor(this)">violet</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#808080"><a href = "#" onclick = "updateColor(this)">grey</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#000000"><a href = "#" onclick = "updateColor(this)">black</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#ffe6e6"><a href = "#" onclick = "updateColor(this)">cream</a></td>
                <td style="background-color:#ff00bf"><a href = "#" onclick = "updateColor(this)">fushia</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```